# Performance issue strcat and hex2dec

Tags: matlab, performance, hex, decimal

The `dec2hex(D)` function in MATLAB returns a 2-D string array where each row is the hexadecimal representation of each decimal integer in D. Suppose I use this function to read my input data (ANSI characters), and convert this data to 1-byte hexadecimal representations, such that the resulting matrix is a *L x 4* char matrix (should be *L x 2* but still). Since there are some 2-byte numbers present in the data I cannot simply convert these hex values to decimal values. Now, to get the decimal value of these 2 byte hex numbers, I use the following line (the later value in the matrix corresponds to the MSB):

```
hex2dec(strcat(data_hex(index+1,:),data_hex(index,:)));
```

So I concatenate the two rows of the hex matrix (each containing 4 columns with single chars), into a single string, and transform this string to decimal. However, this takes a lot of time; this line is executed roughly 7000 times and takes 1.2 seconds. Since this is still a relatively small data set, I'm looking for a faster way to achieve my goal. Note that simply converting the whole hex matrix to decimal numbers takes a negligible amount of time, so I was hoping I could use the decimal representations instead. Any help would be appreciated!

Example for reading a 2-byte hexadecimal number:
- Create a vector consisting of 2 decimal values (e.g. `T = [46 23]`)
- Convert this vector to hexadecimal representation: `T_hex = dec2hex(T)`. The resulting matrix is sized *2x2* and each element is a char (for the example `T_hex=[2E;17]`
- Now I want to read this matrix as a single value `"172E"`, and convert it to a decimal number. For this I used the line above, in this case `hex2dec(strcat(T_hex(2,:),T_hex(1,:)))`, which has 5934 as output

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on what you're trying to do. Full example code with example data would be helpful. It looks like you're iterating over `index` using a loop. Can you not just use `hex2dex(data_hex)` or maybe `hex2dec(flipud(data_hex))`?

Comment: @horchler I added an example, which I hope clarifies my meaning. Indeed, using hex2dec(data_hex) converts all hexadecimal numbers to decimal. However, some data is larger than 1 byte, and thus should "combine" several single byte hexadecimal numbers

Answer (score 0):

Try running `hex2dec` separately on each of the bytes. You can then easily combine the LSB and MSB arrays using `results = 256*MSB + LSB`

You can also try using `sscanf(hexStr,'%x')` rather than `hex2dec(hexStr)`. On my system `sscanf` is 3-4 faster.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Replacing `hex2dec()` with `sscanf` results in a 25% speedup. I'm not sure what you mean with `results=256*MSB + LSB`, because the example this would yield `results = 256*46+23=11799 !=5934`. Could you explain what you mean there?

Comment: In your example, MSB=0x17=23 and LSB=0x2E=46, so 256*MSB+LSB = 256*23+46 = 5934 = 0x172E, as expected. Using this arithmetic computation should be much faster than sscanf or hex2dec when applied to vector inputs.